# ¿Por qué no funcionan modulos en VueJs?, mapGetter "unknown getter:"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy teniendo problemas con con los getters en *VueJS*. Tengo que cambiar mi barra de navegación dependiendo si el usuario está o no autenticado. Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> [vuex] unknown getter: user/is_authenticated

1. Store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

// import getters from './getters'
import user from './modules/user'
import front from './modules/front'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    front,
    user
  },
```

2.user.js

```
const UserModule = {
  state: {
    is_authenticated: false,
    access_token: null,
    id_token: null,
    email: null,
    name: null,
    lastname: null,
    birth_date: null,
    genre: null,
    document_type: null,
    document_number: null,
    nationality: null,
    country_residence: null,
    phone: null
  },
  getters: {
    is_authenticated: state => state.is_authenticated,
  },
...
export default {
  UserModule,
  namespaced: true
}
```

3 NavBar.vue

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['windowsWidth', 'sizes']),
    ...mapGetters('user', ['is_authenticated'])
  },
  mounted () {
    this.menu = routesMenu('portal')
    console.log(this.is_authenticated)
  },
```

El console.log me da `undefined` , y al hacerlo sin el nombre del modulo `...mapGetters(['is_authenticated'])` , me devuelve `false` sin importar que valor le de.
Llevo poco tiempo usando Vue, ya he buscado de todo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y como esta definido el store?

Comment: Ah perdon ahi esta... me confundio el nombre...

Answer (score 0):

Desde user.js estas exportando una constante que tiene el estado, getters, acciones y mutacacion, pero cuando llamas a ese modulo no tienes la estructura correcta.

una opcion es crear cada variable como una constante y exportarlas de forma individual, que es lo mas comun:

```
const state = {
    is_authenticated: false,
    access_token: null,
    id_token: null,
    email: null,
    name: null,
    lastname: null,
    birth_date: null,
    genre: null,
    document_type: null,
    document_number: null,
    nationality: null,
    country_residence: null,
    phone: null
  },
  getters = {
   is_authenticated: state => state.is_authenticated,
  },
...

export default {
  state, getters, actions, mutations
  namespaced: true
}
```

de esta manera accedes a los datos que necesites del modulo.

la otra opcion, que no probe, pero imagino que podria funcionar es editar el mapGetter a algo como:

```
...mapGetters('user', ['UserModule.is_authenticated'])
```

insisto en que no lo probe, y es probable que no funcione.